# How to create a login with multiple passwords

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I tried this but it doesn't works.

HTML:

```
<form id="login" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="login"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

PHP

```
    $login = "citybank";
    $pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2", "ticket1");

    if(isset($_POST["login"])){

        if($_POST["login"] == $login and $_POST["pass"] == $pass){
            echo 'You are logged';
            echo "

            <script>            
            var post = document.querySelector('#login');
            post.style.display = 'none';
            </script>

            ";
        }else{
            echo "You are not logged.";
        }
    }
```

I think i have a problem with my `array`.
I dont know if its right the way i am using.

Thanks

Comment: you have syntax here:- `$pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2, "ticket1");` , `"` missing around `ticket2`. I hope it's a typing mistake only.

Comment: Also don't use this approach for live environment.Big security issue. playing at your local system is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have syntax error here:

```
$pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2, "ticket1"); // missing "
```

Also you searched for value in array, so you should use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<form id="login" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="login"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php


    $login = "citybank";
    $pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2", "ticket1");

    if(isset($_POST["login"])){

        if($_POST["login"] == $login and in_array($_POST["pass"], $pass)){
            echo 'You are logged';
            echo "

            <script>
            var post = document.querySelector('#login');
            post.style.display = 'none';
            </script>

            ";
        }else{
            echo "You are not logged.";
        }
    }

?>
```

**Warning:** Never, ever implement login logic like that, if it is for test it's OK, but on production environment is **FORBIDDEN**!

Here is [example](https://codeshack.io/secure-login-system-php-mysql/) of login system which is secured.

Comment: i got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home//w on line 26

Comment: There is no error in this piece of code, probably error comes from other place ?

Comment: Thanks it works! Apropos, is there a way to delete "ticket3" for exemple from the php file, if someone use this password?

Comment: It's not good idea. But also is not good idea to store passwords like this :P check example :P

Comment: its because i want create coupon in the future, it is just for study

Answer (score 2):

You can use [in_array()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to solve your issue. 
But you should use database to store password.

php

```
$login = "citybank";
$pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2", "ticket1");

if(isset($_POST["login"])){
    if($_POST["login"] == $login && in_array($_POST["pass"], $pass)){
        echo 'You are logged';
        echo "

        <script>            
            var post = document.querySelector('#login');
            post.style.display = 'none';
        </script>

        ";
        }else{
            echo "You are not logged.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $login = "citybank";
    $pass = array("ticket3", "ticket2", "ticket1");

    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        $count=0;

        if($_POST["login"] == $login)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
            {

              if($_POST["pass"] == $pass[$i])
              {
                 {
                    $count=1;
                     echo 'You are logged';
                     echo "
                     <script>            
                     var post = document.querySelector('#login');
                     post.style.display = 'none';
                     </script>
                     ";
                     break;
                 }

               }
            }
            if($count==0)
            {
            echo "You are not logged.";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```